# Horizontal Jquery Scrollbar for Multiple Rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I need a slider with two rows, It is possible in a way, but that's not what I need. Here is the deal;

According to a [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div) I can line up multiple div's horizontally.

But if I need two rows, then it will sort items like this:

[image: Wrong order]

While what I need is this:

[image: Correct order]

(gray area is invisible)

What is the correct method to solve this problem?

The HTML of the code is just like:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="content-slider"></div>
<div id="content-scroll">
  <div id="content-holder">
        <div class="content-item" id="item-1">item 1</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-2">item 2</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-3">item 3</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-4">item 4</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-5">item 5</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-6">item 6</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-7">item 7</div>
        <div class="content-item" id="item-8">item 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It's OK to play with the CSS but I am looking for a solution with minimal interference with the HTML code.

Comment: you could create a table for this.

Comment: I am always avoiding tables on my web projects. I don't think they are user-designer friendly for this age.

Comment: I'm not saying make the entire website table layout based.  I would encapsulate a table within a div and place each content-item in a table cell... otherwise it's over complicated.  There's nothing wrong with using tables as long as you use them correctly and in situations that require it.

Answer (score 2):

Working closely to the style of the example, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GBr6e/

I have arranged the markup into columns consisting of two items, tweaking the css slightly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work since I don't know what specific data goes to which column.

Comment: But it could also work as a final alternative. (adding container div's for every 2 items in the original holder using a loop on jquery)